# Problem with Opportunity fieldMap describe method

Tags: opportunity

I have used this code:

```
    Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > fieldMap = schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
    String theQueryOpp = 'SELECT Id, AccountId';
    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keyset()) {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDesc = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
        if (fieldDesc.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST) {
           String theName = fieldDesc.getName();
           theQueryOpp += ', ' + theName;
        }
    }
    theQueryOpp += '  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = \'' + opp.Id + '\'limit 1';
    list < Opportunity > opportunity = Database.query(theQueryOpp);
```

I have not seen any fields in debug log. All permission are given on all fields and user's profile is system admin. Can anybody tell me what is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean when you output the `theQueryOpp` string you don't see the fields? The describe code looks OK to me.

Comment: Yes. There is no field in output of theQueryOpp string..

Comment: Strange as fields appear for me in the SOQL string using "Execute Anonymous" and a SA login. The fields being missing from the profile is all I can think of but you have checked that.

Comment: No, I have checked that already. All fields are native that I required and present in profile.

Comment: Are you actually writing to the debug log? Have you turned on the debug log for your user account? Have you refreshed the debug log? One of these things will likely be the problem.

Comment: Of course I am writing to debug log for the same user and properly refreshed.